# Fetch not waiting for complete file download from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, fetch, blob

I am using firebase to storage my 5 jpegs.
I need to download them and pass them to function to retrieve EXIF data from them.
To accomplish that tash i have made bellow script which is:

1. checking how many files are in specific folder in database
2. getting download url's for every file
3. looping through every url and executing function wchich is downloading files from those url's

The problem is: first four images are downloaded properly. The last one is allways not downloaded completelly.

Please see bellow code. Note fucntion called getHTML1 is redundant do getHTML, and gives the same result.
I just tried different approach.

TLDR:
How to make fetch wait for last file being completelly downloaded?

```
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  listAll,
  getDownloadURL
} from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
const listRef = ref(storage, 'images');

const firebaseDownloadHandler = async() => {
  function getHTML1(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('get', url);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function() {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 200) {
          let blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {
            type: 'image/jpeg'
          })
          console.log(xhr.response);
          resolve(blob);
        } else {
          reject(status);
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    });
  }

  function getHTML(url) {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      await fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
          type: 'image/jpeg'
        })
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
          resolve(blob)
        });
    })
  }

  const res = await listAll(listRef);
  const requests = res.items.map(itemRef => getDownloadURL(itemRef))
  const urls = await Promise.all(requests);
  const processArray = async() => {
    console.log(urls);
    const finalResult = [];
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const result = await getHTML(urls[i + 1]);
        finalResult.push(result);
        if (finalResult.length === urls.length) {
          resolve(finalResult);
        }
      }
    })
  };

  const downloaded = await processArray();
  return await downloaded;
}

export default firebaseDownloadHandler;
```

result:

```
20:06:11.499
Array(5) [ "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/geolocf.appspot.…025.jpg?alt=media&token=8ecbfc6d-07ed-4205-9599-a6e36dd444ed", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/geolocf.appspot.…028.jpg?alt=media&token=06a422fa-64f2-482f-9f63-c39aaf1d9354", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/geolocf.appspot.…855.jpg?alt=media&token=6ae03b2c-bd82-49fc-bcb6-0de0683e7d50", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/geolocf.appspot.…402.jpg?alt=media&token=a22ef4dd-7f79-40aa-90df-57ad73b10248", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/geolocf.appspot.…646.jpg?alt=media&token=e04958d0-ed2f-44f6-9931-18644ffbe8b8" ]
firebaseDownloadHandler.js:45
20:06:14.882
Array(5) [ Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob ]
​
0: Blob { size: 6428869, type: "image/jpeg" }
​
1: Blob { size: 7402504, type: "image/jpeg" }
​
2: Blob { size: 2858717, type: "image/jpeg" }
​
3: Blob { size: 3045876, type: "image/jpeg" }
​
4: Blob { size: 2278, type: "text/html; charset=utf-8" }
​
length: 5
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but you're overusing custom promises.

As far as I can see, this function:

```
function getHTML(url) {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        type: 'image/jpeg'
      })
      .then(res => res.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        resolve(blob)
      });
  })
}
```

Can be shorted to this without any change in functionality:

```
function getHTML(url) {
  return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      type: 'image/jpeg'
    })
    .then(res => res.blob())
}
```

Comment: That's right. Same functionality. 
I'm trying everything to get this waiting for last file.
Nothing changed with this shortened function.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Error is not caused by fetch itself.
I wrongly passed urls to fetching function.

Should be

```
const result = await getHTML(urls[i]);
```

Instead of

```
const result = await getHTML(urls[i + 1]);
```